DOM Element not found when modifying font size with `message.info` components
How do I use Antd library message.info components to modify CSS font-size?
It's not working, it's not found DOM element:
import { message } from 'antd'

message.info({
  content: 'info',
  style: {
    fontSize: '8px',
    lineHeight: '1.5'
  }
})


You will likely need to provide more code and information
